# Convert DataFrame into dictionary of key as index and values as other columns as list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, collections

Take panda dataframe as

```
index    A    B
1        5    6
2        8    10
```

Convert this into dictionary like

```
{'1':[5, 6], '2':[8, 10]}
```

Is conversion possible in python? If yes, please give code in efficient way.